# Perforce trigger to deny merge from certain branches

Tags: merge, triggers, perforce

I would like to create a trigger that prevents the option of merging from certain branch to another certain branch.

[It is kind of doing what streams do]

Comment: I'm glad to hear you recognize streams would do what you want to do. Another option is using the protections table to exclude write permission to the certain branch. Otherwise, using your favorite flavor of script, write a "change-submit" trigger to preclude submits when change includes "//path-to-certain-branch-A" and "//path-to-certain-branch-B"

Answer (score 1):

To deny merging from a particular branch you can remove the `=branch` permission in the protection table:

```
=branch group X * -//depot/source/branch/...
```

(See `p4 help protect` and maybe `p4 help undoc`, I forget if `=branch` ever got out of `undoc` status...)

To prevent the combination of a particular source and a particular target, you'll need a trigger.  Have the trigger fire on the target path, and have it run "p4 resolved" to look for pending integrations from the source path.